# On edit, move edited document to different folder with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am making documents through an IFTTT recipe and after I edit it, I want to be able to differentiate it from the rest by moving it to a different folder.

How would I do this? Would adding it count as a change so its second edit?

I was looking at `onedit()`, but I couldn't understand how to use it and I didn't know how to make it work for any/all documents (it could be checked for all files in one folder, but this is all I use Google Drive for, so any folder would also work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brute-force way is to create a function that iterates over the files comparing the create date-time versus the last edit date-time. This is available via `getDateCreated()` and `getLastUpdated()` methods of the [file class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_file). Read up about file quantity limits and handling paged requests if you have a sizable number of files. Your function could be run using any of [the normal ways a GAS script is executed](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_methods). Once you have the function working, manually creating a time driven trigger will run it automatically as frequently as you wish.

In gDrive "folders" are really display convention for a type of tag associated with a file. Like gMail labels, dDrive folders can be nested and one file can "be in" multiple folders at the same time. Below is a little function to prove adding a file to a folder does not change the last updated date/time stamp. "Moving" a file is functionally the same as adding it to one folder and removing it from another.

```
function FileEditTagTest() {
  var start = 1
  var max = 1
  var files = DocsList.getAllFiles(start, max)        //get array with one arbitrar file
  var id = files[0].getId()                           //get the file's ID
  var file = DocsList.getFileById(id)                 //get the file object
  Logger.log("Name:        " + file.getName())        //log the file's name
  Logger.log("LastUpdate:  " + file.getLastUpdated()) //log the file date-time before adding it to a new folder
  var folderName = 'TagTest' + new Date();            //generate a unique folder name. Current date is used for convenient uniquness
  var root = DocsList.getRootFolder()                 //get the root folder for the user
  var folder = root.createFolder(folderName)          //create a new folder
  file.addToFolder(folder)                            //assign the folder to the file (aka "put the file there")
  Logger.log("FolderName:  " + folderName)            //log the folder name
  Logger.log("LastUpdate:  " + file.getLastUpdated()) //log the file date-time after adding it to a new folder
}
```

After running this function, the log will look similar to the following. Note how the two entries for last update are identical.

```
Name:        YourFileNameHere
LastUpdate:  Fri Mar 15 2013 15:32:42 GMT-0600 (CST)
FolderName:  TagTestFri Mar 15 2013 18:50:37 GMT-0600 (CST)
LastUpdate:  Fri Mar 15 2013 15:32:42 GMT-0600 (CST)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are talking about text documents, not spreadsheets (?).  OnEdit applies to spreadsheets so it won't work for your use case.  Moreover, there is no way to have a script bound to a text document... the only possible way I can imagine is to have a standalone script that monitors the documents activity and tries to detect if a new doc has been created and is eventually being edited but I'm not sure even how to do that.

When you say  *" and after i edit it "* does it mean you edit it manually after that that your IFTTT service has created it ? Does that happen in a limited/defined time lapse ?

If timing is not too critical perhaps you can imagine a timer triggered monitoring script that inspects your drive and moves files corresponding to some specific criteria to another folder...

I'm afraid you'll have to give more details on what is happening to these documents in the process if you want a better advise. (sorry for this rather 'vague' response)

Comment: Im sorry i was so vague also, yes it is to text documents and yes IFTTT manually makes it and I edit it after if its made(if that makes any sense), there is no definite time scale but its always within a two weeks. I like the idea of the criteria(although if you/we could figure out how to "monitor the document activity that would be ideal"), there are certain repetitive tasks i could do for each one(simple somewhat formatting things i.e. a space here, etc) so maybe if you could detect the value of the text document and it has this... it would move it. I just dont want to make it too arbitrary.